# Корзина битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Можете объяснить каким образом работает корзина битрикс. Знаю как формируется каталог товаров и тд. Но немного не понимаю в какой массив помещаются данные из карточки товара для передачи в корзину. И где можно почитать  об этом.
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

/** int $productId ID товара */
/** int $quantity количество */
if ($item = $basket->getExistsItem('catalog', $productId)) {
    $item->setField('QUANTITY', $item->getQuantity() + $quantity);
} else {
    $item = $basket->createItem('catalog', $productId);
    $item->setFields([
        'QUANTITY' => $quantity,
        'CURRENCY' => Bitrix\Currency\CurrencyManager::getBaseCurrency(),
        'LID' => Bitrix\Main\Context::getCurrent()->getSite(),
        'PRODUCT_PROVIDER_CLASS' => 'CCatalogProductProvider',
    ]);
    /*
    Если вы хотите добавить товар с произвольной ценой, нужно сделать так:
    $item->setFields([
        'QUANTITY' => $quantity,
        'CURRENCY' => Bitrix\Currency\CurrencyManager::getBaseCurrency(),
        'LID' => Bitrix\Main\Context::getCurrent()->getSite(),
        'PRICE' => $customPrice,
        'CUSTOM_PRICE' => 'Y',
    ]);
    */
}
$basket->save();
```

---

Почитать для понимания работы:

[Хорошая документация по работе с корзиной (D7)](https://mrcappuccino.ru/blog/post/work-with-basket-bitrix-d7)

[Официальная документация по работе с корзиной](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/sale/technique/basket.php)

[Официальная документация по компоненту "Корзина" (sale.basket.basket)](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/magazin/basket/sale_basket_basket.php)

Answer (score 0):

Корзина в CMS Bitrix представляет собой инструмент для управления товарами, выбранными пользователем для покупки. Работа с корзиной основана на использовании API модуля "Интернет-магазин" (`sale`).

1. **Добавление товара в корзину**: Когда пользователь добавляет товар в корзину, из карточки товара собирается информация (например, ID товара, количество, цена и др.) и передается в специальный массив. Этот массив затем используется для добавления товара в корзину через API. Пример функции для добавления товара в корзину:

```php
CModule::IncludeModule("sale");

$arFields = array(
    "PRODUCT_ID" => $productID,
    "PRICE" => $productPrice,
    "CURRENCY" => "RUB",
    "QUANTITY" => $productQuantity,
    "LID" => LANG,
    "DELAY" => "N",
    "CAN_BUY" => "Y",
    "NAME" => $productName,
);

CSaleBasket::Add($arFields);
```

2. **Данные корзины**: Все товары, добавленные в корзину, хранятся в таблице базы данных `b_sale_basket`. Также сессии пользователей ассоциируются с их корзинами, что позволяет системе идентифицировать содержимое корзины для каждого пользователя.
3. **Управление корзиной**: С помощью API можно не только добавлять товары в корзину, но и изменять количество товара, удалять товар из корзины и т. д.
4. **Документация**: Подробную информацию по работе с корзиной, а также с другими аспектами модуля "Интернет-магазин", можно найти в официальной документации Bitrix на их сайте.

В зависимости от редакции и настроек вашего Bitrix, а также от индивидуальных доработок, конкретные детали работы с корзиной могут варьироваться. Если у вас есть доступ к коду сайта, рекомендую изучить файлы компонентов, связанных с корзиной, чтобы лучше понять, каким образом передаются и обрабатываются данные.

Comment: Ощущается дух ChatGPT...